# What do you call a plastic tube or pipe that is made of plastic and flexible?

Tags: word-usage, word-request

I'm trying to think what this thing is called in English:

[image]

This is something that we use, in my country, to connect a tap water to water some plants.

Anyway, if I have to call it based on my current knowledge, I'd say it's a **plastic tube**, **plastic pipe**, or **flexi pipe**. To make it sure that I was not wrong, I looked them up.

This is what **a plastic tube** looks like according to Google Image:

[image]

Although it looks similar, I don't think this what I should call that thing. Because, to me, it more looks like a thing that connects a liquid (Ringer's Lactate) through your hand when you're at the hospital. The diameter is too small.

This is a **plastic pipe**

[image]

And this is a **flexi pipe**

[image]

The last image above is by far almost looks like the thing I want to know its name. But no, since it looks like something to dispose of water from a washing machine.

What do you call that thing in English?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**hose**

From Merriam-Webster:

> **2 :** a flexible tube for conveying fluids (as from a faucet or hydrant)

In particular, we always use "hose" to describe the thing that we connect to a tap to water plants.

Your image looks more like plastic tubing though. This is what a typical garden hose looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**plastic-tubing**

[image: plastic-tubing example]

[Source](https://cneastophose.en.made-in-china.com/product/BXAxdTpbYcRU/China-Thin-Wall-PVC-Hose-Clear-Plastic-Tubing-with-Low-Medium-Pressure.html)

> Plastic tubing is a form of tubing that is manufactured from a mixture of a polymer and a variety of chemicals to form a material that can be solid or flexible. [Source](https://www.iqsdirectory.com/articles/plastic-tubing.html)